# How to print a message in broker log

Tags: ibm-mq, messagebroker

I've been searching on internet and ESQL/WebSphere MessageBroker documentations, to find a way of printing a variable's value so that i can trace it in Broker Logs. Like System.out.println() in java.

I can't debug the messageflow because of some technical issues, so could you please suggest me how to do it or any workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

UserTrace is supposed to fulfil this role for ESQL but if UserTrace isn't helping then I see a lot of people use static calls out from ESQL to java whcih are then logged.

The java code could be as simple as writing to stdout (which will go in /var/mqsi/components//stdout) but more commonly I see this pattern used with existing java logging frameworks like log4J.

The advantage of this approach is that you unify logging between your JCN's and ESQL compute nodes.

Answer (score 1):

User Trace should suffice your need, Put a trace node at the point where you want to log, select the file trace and give a file path, 
pattern give as:

```
${CURRENT_TIMESTAMP}
${Root}
${Environment}
${LocalEnvironment}
${ExceptionList}
```

so it logs everything.

If it's in higher environments, then you have to use the `mqsichangetrace` command to enable the trace on flow.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is:

1) Set a temporary location in the Environment to the value of the variable: SET Environment.temp = yourVar ;

2) Subsequently, in a Trace node, set the Pattern on the Basic tab of the Trace node to that temporary location: ${Environment.temp}

3) Configure the Trace node to print to a File, User Trace, or the Local Error Log.

4) Deploy and run your flow.  Then look in the output of the Trace node.

Comment: Worth noting that in the IBM documentation, it says to use Environment.Variables for locally-created variables - see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.scenarios.doc/gop_03/topics/bj60052_.htm